# Arduino as HID device on Windows - Bind external button presses to a keymap in the OS?

Tags: input, arduino, usb, external

Here's the problem: I want to press an external button attached to an Arduino, and I want that button press to translate into Windows as a keystroke.

My question is, is there a programmable device (I already own an Arduino) that can receive signals, and send them over USB to my computer which will understand it as a keypress
Example: Button press acts like hitting the S key on my keyboard?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

There are three (four) possibilities:
First Get an Arduino Leonardo (32U4 architecture) - there are HID drivers (so windows recognizes the hardware - short explanation: The Arduino LEONARDO is an integrated USB HID Arduino board. Ideal for projects requiring the board to behave (act) as a USB human interface devices = HID).
Two Use any other Arduino and install Processing with the relevant modules. Write code on both and use Processing to translate to windows.

Three I've seen some more or less working implementations.
[Example 1](https://hackaday.com/2012/06/29/turning-an-arduino-into-a-usb-keyboard/)
[Example 2](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Uno-Into-Usb-Keyboard/)
[Example 3](http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/) Scroll down and you will see a [picture of your button solution](http://mitchtech.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/arduino_3button.png) including code.
(Four) This requires also windows programming skills. Write an usb "driver" a translating engine for I/O between Arduino on usb and acting like a virtual (e.g. touch screen) keyboard. Thats the hardest way to go.